# Why does JQuery Clip not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the clip function in JQuery. I'm simply experimenting with the functionality. I cannot seem to get the function to work however. I want the image to squeeze into nothing over a second. Here is a code snippet of what I'm working with.

```
$(".leftstrip").hide("clip", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1000);
```

When I try to run this I am getting this error:

> "object doesn't support property or method '[object Object]'

I have been working with Jquery 1.11. I pulled examples from the web of using the clip function with that same problem. This occurs in IE and Chrome. What could be wrong with my setup?

Comment: jQuery has no native clip function. Are you referring to the clip effect in jQuery UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clip` animation effect requires [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/download/)(or at least the effects component of it), not just jQuery:
http://api.jqueryui.com/clip-effect/